# Modx manager custom page check if user is logged in and has manager access

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am developing modx manager custom page and cannot check if user is logged in and has access to manager ? So far I tried

```
$modx->user->get('username');
```

All i get is **(anonymous)** even if i am logged in and when i am not logged in.I have also tried sessioncontext etc as well. Am i doing something wrong. Did anyone faced same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom snippet to manage showing things for people who are logged in or not and the [Login Extra](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/login/login.profile) to easily access user fields. Then paste this in and call it `isAdmin`:

```
<?php
if ($modx->user instanceof modUser) {
    if ($modx->user->hasSessionContext('mgr')) { 
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

And then you want to use it like this...

```
[[!isAdmin:notempty=`
    <!-- Do something for people logged in -->

`:default=`
    <!-- Do something for everyone else -->
`]]
```

Code is from [Mark Hamstra's blog](https://www.markhamstra.com/modx/2012/01/hiding-google-analytics-code-from-manager-users/).

Comment: I created snippet and called it from my php file located in base_url/modules/demo/check.php file using var_dump($modx->runSnippet('isManagerLogin'));
method but it doesnt work. returns string(0) ""